# How do I make the -ms-thumb pseudo element register pointer events on underlying range input in two input overlay in IE?

Tags: css, sass, slider, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I want to make a range input with two handles. I have made one overlaying two inputs with type range. I use the css property pointer events to disable the track from intercepting any click meant to hit the underlying thumb. This works fine in Chrome and in Firefox. Is does not seems to pickup any pointer events in IE 11 or Edge. How do I get the `-ms-thumb` pseudo element to pick up the pointer events?

I have prepared a code pen to illustrate the problem. https://codepen.io/RemkoBoschker/pen/jzLgXq

The same code is included below

```css
@mixin thumb($input-height, $input-border-radius, $input-thumb-color) {
    width: $input-height;
    height: $input-height;
    border: none;
    pointer-events: auto;
    border-radius: $input-border-radius;
    background-color: $input-thumb-color;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* https://codepen.io/rendykstan/pen/VLqZGO8 */
@mixin range-slider(
    $width,
    $height,
    $input-top,
    $input-bg-color,
    $input-thumb-color,
    $float: none,
    $input-height: 20px,
    $input-border-radius: 14px,
    $bubble-width: 100px
) {
    position: relative;
    width: $width;
    margin-left: (100% - $width) / 2;
    height: $height;
    float: $float;
    text-align: center;

    input[type='range'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        pointer-events: none;
        height: $input-height;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: $input-top;
        height: $input-height;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: $input-border-radius;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        background: none;
        &:focus,
        &:active {
            outline: none;
        }
        &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            @include thumb($input-height, $input-border-radius, $input-thumb-color);
        }
        &::-moz-range-thumb {
            @include thumb($input-height, $input-border-radius, $input-thumb-color);
        }
        &::-ms-thumb {
            @include thumb($input-height, $input-border-radius, $input-thumb-color);
        }
        &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
            /* your track styles */
        }
        &::-moz-range-track {
            -moz-appearance: none;
            background: none;
        }
        &::-ms-track {
            /* should come after -webkit- */
            border-color: transparent;
            color: transparent;
            background: transparent;
            /* again your track styles */
        }
        &::-ms-fill-upper {
            background: transparent;
        }
        &::-ms-fill-lower {
            background: transparent;
        }
        &::-ms-tooltip {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

.range-slider {
        @include range-slider(80%, 54px, 30px, #f1efef, green, left, 20px, 14px, 80px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="range-slider">
    <input type="range" step="1" min="0" max="10" value=5>
    <input type="range" step="1" min="0" max="10" value="3">
</div>
```

I have also written a cross-browser version using js.

https://codepen.io/RemkoBoschker/pen/bvaQBw

I also posted a bug report with Microsoft

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16592591/

Comment: I've just come up against the same problem - did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: In my post there is a link to javascript based work-around. I never got any feedback from the Edge team.

Comment: Yeah thanks. CodePen doesn't work in IE any more, so I wasn't able to see if it worked there, but I'll give it a go. Cheers :)